# Escape HTML to process PHP

Tags: php

I am using this code but the PHP part `<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>` is not rendered.

```
function choose_bar() {
    $html = <<<HTML
<div class="memlog"><a class="mem-in ttmem x-btn x-btn-small" href="/login/" ><i class="x-icon-globe" data-x-icon="&#xf0ac;"></i>Login</a><a class="mem-out ttmem x-btn x-btn-small" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a></div>
HTML;

    return $html;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a specific requirement with WordPress to do this as a Heredoc string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use PHP tags (`<?php ... ?>`) inside a heredoc string (the `<<<HTML ... HTML;` in your code). While variables (`$foo`) are evaluated, functions (`wp_logout_url()`) and PHP tags are not.

The easiest solution is this: Just define a variable and use it in your HTML instead of calling the function `wp_logout_url()`.

Working example:

```
function choose_bar() {
    $logoutUrl = wp_logout_url();
    $html = <<<HTML
<div class="memlog"><a class="mem-in ttmem x-btn x-btn-small" href="/login/" ><i class="x-icon-globe" data-x-icon="&#xf0ac;"></i>Login</a><a class="mem-out ttmem x-btn x-btn-small" href="$logoutUrl" title="Logout">Logout</a></div>
HTML;

    return $html;
}
```

Also, FYI, there's no need for a declaration of `$html` here; you can just do a return:

```
function choose_bar() {
    $logoutUrl = wp_logout_url();
    return <<<HTML
<div class="memlog"><a class="mem-in ttmem x-btn x-btn-small" href="/login/" ><i class="x-icon-globe" data-x-icon="&#xf0ac;"></i>Login</a><a class="mem-out ttmem x-btn x-btn-small" href="$logoutUrl" title="Logout">Logout</a></div>
HTML;
}
```